# How do I define clientWidth in JS for my ruby app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a lot of trouble getting any javascripts to run in my Ruby application.

Currently my console is giving me one error message:

"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined**"

This error is referencing this line in my *application.js* file:

```
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
```

I'm guessing it's saying it has no idea what clientWidth is? I was following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcdBOoK3Pfw) when I hit this roadblock. (He's not making a rails app, but his script loads fine.) The script also loaded fine for me when I created a regular index.html page not tied to my ruby app.

### How do I define clientWidth/do I need to?

My Rails files:

**Gem File**

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'
gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

<%= javascript_include_tag( 'slider.js' ) %>

</head>
<body> <!--Body and html tags are closed in my _footer.html.erb -->
```

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require turbolinks


$(document).ready to $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(main());

//image slider code
//
//

const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');

const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


//buttons

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


//Counter

let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+(-size * counter)+ 'px)';
```

**slider.html.erb**

```
<button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<br /><br />

<div class="carousel-container">
<div class="carousel-slide"> 
<%= image_tag("photo4.jpg", id: "lastClone") %> 
<!-- photo1.jpg is an image of a road at sunset should have the border around it and be the focus. Currently, it is not. -->
<%= image_tag("photo1.jpg") %> 
<%= image_tag("photo2.jpg") %>
<%= image_tag("photo3.jpg") %>
<%= image_tag("photo4.jpg") %>
<%= image_tag("photo1.jpg", id: "firstClone") %>
</div>
</div>
```

**slider.scss**

```
/* This is for a test slider */

.carousel-container {
  width: 1000px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.carousel-slide {
  display: flex;

  img{
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Here is an imgur link to see a screenshot of my ruby app vs. a regular .html file I created to compare/contrast what is going on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhkki.jpg

Here are the versions I am running of things:

**Ruby**: ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

**Node**: v13.2.0

**NPM**: 6.13.1

I tried a few different suggestions found via google searches (a la 'get fixed quick'), so if anything is off or out of place, please point it out to me. If you require more info/code, I will be happy to provide.

Any help getting my Javascript to run would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined` this error means `carouselImages[0]` is undefined... please use `debugger` and make sure you are getting all images correctly

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to do with *ruby* but with the **javascript** itself.

The problem is at querySelectorAll, it isn't returning the right value + i suggest not to use it because it **isn't supported** in every browser.
So just add a class to each image and everything would be easier :)

A working demo for you :

```
<div class="carousel-slide"> 
<%= image_tag("photo4.jpg", id: "lastClone"), class: "imgCarousel" %> 
<%= image_tag("photo1.jpg"), class: "imgCarousel" %> 
<%= image_tag("photo2.jpg"), class: "imgCarousel" %>
</div>
```

At javascript :

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("imgCarousel")[0];
console.log(x.clientWidth)
```

Demo (**with JS and html**):

```js
function myFunction() {
  x=document.getElementsByClassName("imgCarousel")[0];
  console.log(x.clientWidth)
  document.getElementById("widthContainer").innerHTML = x.clientWidth
}
```

```html
<body>

<img class="imgCarousel" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif" >
<img class="imgCarousel" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif" >
<img class="imgCarousel" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif" >


<p id="widthContainer">Click the button to get clientWidth of first image.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, this did not fix my problem.

Comment: I updated my answer, I added the demo in there using HTML and JS (your problem is here not at RUBY, it works  just check it carefully :)
Feel free to upvote + accepted answer